# my multi curl script start working after verifying all sites

Tags: php, curl

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$targetsfile = $argv[1];
if(!isset($argv[1])) { echo "[-] Try again... with targets file.\n"; die(); }
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);


$nodes = array();
$nodes = file("$targetsfile", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$node_count = count($nodes);

$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();

for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; pt-pt) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27";
    $url = $nodes[$i];
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
}
do
{
    curl_multi_exec($master, $running);
    usleep(5000);
} while($running > 0);

for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl_arr[$i], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<=300) {
         $crawledlink = curl_getinfo($curl_arr[$i], CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
         echo "Parsing->" . $crawledlink;
    }
}
?>
```

How should i do for my script to start parsing the sites WHILE he verify the http code because right now i was thinking when i wrote the code it will parsing the sites while he verify for http code but it doesn't... First verify all my targets http code and then start to parsing... I want the script to start parsing sites immediatelly he found 1 with http code 200-299 like I specified.

Any advice?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php

Comment: @John - its not a bad question, but its not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish. Can you clarify what you mean with *"... to start parsing the sites WHILE he verify the http code..."* The HTTP response header is sent first, before the body arrives (assuming an OK response header). What is the significance of the *WHILE* (emphasis yours)?

Comment: I mean... my script now start to parsing sites after verfy all the targets from the file specified but i want to start parsing sites while he verify the sites [see first for loop].